# How to reset the value of a nested object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below the given object i need to reset the value for the key "label", "value", "ward" and "tole" to empty(' ') using javascript.

```
state ={
         "label": "लुम्बिनी प्रदेश",
         "value": 21,

         "province": {
            "label": "लुम्बिनी प्रदेश",
            "value": "23"
         },
         "district": {
            "label": "अर्घाखाँची",
            "value": "20"
         },
         "local_level": {
            "label": "भूमिकास्थान नगरपालिका",
            "value": "17"
         },
         "ward": "10",
         "tole": "venas"
       }
```

I have tried to get the keys of the object

```
Object.keys(state).map(item=>({key: item}))
```

but don't have idea how to reset the value of the object.

The final result should look like this.
the state object may evolve i.e the key and value of the object may be added or may be removed.

```
state ={
         "label": '',
         "value": '',

         "province": {
            "label": '',
            "value": ''
         },
         "district": {
            "label": '',
            "value": ''
         },
         "local_level": {
            "label": '',
            "value": ''
         },
         "ward": '',
         "tole": ''
       }
```

Comment: What should the end result look like? Also, how is this used in [tag:reactjs]?

Comment: i want to add that the sate object is not an static object, it is dynamic in nature. It means that the element in the state object may varies. In this case i want to  set, object's, all keys  to empty i.e  keyname : ' ' .

Comment: Please just edit your question to show what the result should be

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the object using the `for...in` Loop in JS. And then, if you find those keys, then just replace their values with an empty string. And since, you also want to check again, that if the value of the keys are objects, and if they are, then you can again loop through them, and change their value to an empty string.

```js
for (let key in state) {
  if (typeof state[key] === 'object') {
    
    // if the value of the key is an object, then we will again loop through the value of that key, and change the value of those keys to an empty string.

    for (let nestedKey in state[key]) {
      // console.log(nestedKey, state[key][nestedKey]);
      
      if (
        nestedKey === "label" ||
        nestedKey === "value" ||
        nestedKey === "ward" ||
        nestedKey === "tole"
      ) {
        state[key][nestedKey] = " ";
      }
    }
  }

  if (key === "label" || key === "value" || key === "ward" || key === "tole") {
    state[key] = " ";
  }
}
```

This code will work, and will change all those values to empty string.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let setToDefault = state => Object.assign(state, { label: '', value: '', ward: '', tole: '' });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, your solution would run perfectly if the state object is an static object. Sorry, but miss to add that the state object is not an static object. The state object is dynamic in nature i.e it is not jst fixed to the given keys and values.